# Create file in Eclipse plugin without actually saving the file?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I would like to know if there is a way to create a file and not saving the file or going through any wizard screen. For instance, I would like to click a button, open a file with a default name, modify the file and optionally save the file into the hard drive.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to open an editor programmatically, you can use one of the static `openEditor()` methods provided by the `IDE` class, for example `openEditor( IWorkbenchPage, IEditorInput, String )`.

You are free to implement a custom `IEditorInput` or more useful in this case probably, the specialized `IStorageEditorInput` interface. Your implementation of `getStorage()` may return a storage that provides content that is independent of an (existing) file.

However, existing editors may or may not *understand* certain editor input types. Unfortunately, there is no way to determine upfront whether a certain editor can handle a certain input type.

If you are implementing your own editor (see `IEditorPart` and `EditorPart`) however, you can, of course, tailor the editor for that input type.

The answers to this question have pointers to building editors in Eclipse in general: [Tutorial regarding the development of a custom Eclipse editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786884/tutorial-regarding-the-development-of-a-custom-eclipse-editor)